# Вращение текста на canvas

Tags: android, kotlin

Который день не могу понять почему текст поворачивается не так как я хочу. Подскажите пожалуйста как нужно сделать.
У меня имеется текстовое представление которое можно перемещать, вращать, увеличивать или уменьшать. Когда TextView не имеет какого то угла поворота, то текст на canvas отрисовывается нормально. Не смотрите на смещение по оси Y, это шрифт такой.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее когда я задаю угол поворота, TextView вращается вокруг своего центра, а текст на canvas, вращается в начале координат, где отрисовывыется TextView.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот ещё фото.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, что бы текст на canvas вращался тоже вокруг своего центра.
Вот код.

```
canvas.save()
            canvas.rotate(i.rotation, x,y)
            canvas.drawText(i.text.toString(),x,y,paint)
            canvas.restore()
```

Там где x,y это координаты для нанесения TextView на canvas.
Они просчитываются исходя из размеров самой фотографии на которую наносится текст.
Суть в том, что когда текст не имеет угла поворота, отображается всё нормально, как только есть поворот, появляется следующая проблема.

Comment: Используйте метод drawTextOnPath

Comment: @Style-7 Каким образом ?

Comment: методом вызова метода объекта canvas